# Confluent Kafka how to get specific topic metadata without subscribe

Tags: apache-kafka, metadata, confluent-platform

I use some code for determination difference between read offsets and max values. It needed for inner diagnostics, for example if difference below "base line" value - so, read speed is good.

Provided code sample works good, but I should to know partition count for topic. And, later get max offset value for each partition in a topic.

How to get topic metadata without subscribing to a topic?

Something like: topic "TestTopic" have 4 partitions.

```
    public async Task MaxOffsetValues()
    {
        // just for tests
        // ToDo: use config from settings

        while (true)
        {
            var topicName = "testTopic";
            var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "192.168.1.1:9092,192.168.1.2:9092,192.168.1.3:9092",
                GroupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ClientId = Dns.GetHostName(),
                EnableAutoCommit = false,
            };

            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
            {
                var offsetBorders = consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(new TopicPartition(topicName, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                _log.Debug($"[Diagnostic] Topic: ({topicName}), Partition: ({0}) Minimal offset: ({offsetBorders.Low}) Maximum offset: ({offsetBorders.High})");
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for programmatic & non-programmatic way to get metadata then there are 3 ways you can get information about a topic without subscribing it.

1. Admin client (https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html)
2. If you have access to confluent-control-center then it does show metadata about a topic.
3. You can also use Kafka-topics.sh CLI tool

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try with "admin client"

Answer (score 0):

For my goal was enought (code part reduced for clarity):

```
// ...
var brokerServers = _diagnosticSettings.Value.BrokerHosts;
var brokerDelayInSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_diagnosticSettings.Value.BrokerDelayInSeconds);

var adminClientConfig = new AdminClientConfig
    {
        BootstrapServers = brokerServers,
        ClientId = Dns.GetHostName(),
    };

adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(adminClientConfig).Build();

Metadata topicMetadata = null;

topicMetadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(topicExternalName, brokerDelayInSeconds);

partitionCount = topicMetadata.Topics[0].Partitions.Count;

// ...
```